# Why is one of my range's ovens cooking unevenly?

Tags: oven

I have a Whirlpool double electric oven. My bottom oven is overcooking food on the bottom and the food is undercooked on the top. Top oven is fine. It is a Whirlpool gold series electric double oven. Only bottom oven has this problem.

Comment: Are you referring to bake or broil mode? Do both heating elements seem to be working?

Comment: You can get little fans that go in the oven to make them convection, which would even out the cooking considerably.

Comment: you may be setting the bottom oven temperature too high

Comment: Have you put a thermometer in the ovens to see what temperature they’re actually getting to?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the top element of the bottom oven is not working.

A typical modern electric oven has two elements. The top element is used for broil *and* bake. The bottom element is only used for bake. Some ovens also have a convection mode, where a fan blows circulates air for more even and faster baking, especially if you have food on more than one oven rack. In my KitchenAid, which is made by Whirlpool, only the top oven has convection, presumably because most people who will make use of the convection mode don't need it all that often, so one oven with the mode is enough. I mention that because you may be in a similar situation - i.e., if you have convection it is likely only in the top oven, which won't help you here.

The way you can tell if an oven element is working properly is to see if glows orange or red. Many ovens (including, Whirlpool Gold, at least the current models) have a hidden bottom element, so you don't actually see it running. But your bottom element is probably fine. So the first thing is to set the oven on broil for a few minutes and see if the top element glows. If it does not glow, then that is the problem (probably the element, but possibly a fuse or relay).

If it does glow then set the oven to bake. When preheating the top element is normally on, at least part of the time, in order to preheat quickly. If it glows then I have no idea what is going on. But if it does not glow then the problem is in the control circuits - i.e., they are not turning the top element on in bake mode.

Unfortunately, control circuits for Whirlpool/KitchenAid ovens are relatively expensive repairs, so the next step (unless it is "element doesn't glow at all, even in broil mode") can get a bit expensive.